# how to urlfetch function in a different google apps script with/

Tags: function, google-apps-script, urlfetch

Hi I would like to know how to call a function in a different google project with urlfetch.fetch, any help is appreciated!

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/scripts/run

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand how to use that, is there an example that i can look at?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/samples/execute